# How to apply highlight for material datatable filter

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, highlight

I want to highlight the text that is searched in the datatable filter field, I am using material data table with angular.
I create a pipe for highlight, and send the text search as an arg

```
export class HighlightSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
 private destroyed$: Subject<void> = new ReplaySubject(1);

 constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
   if (!value) {
   return observableOf(value);
  }

/** Data table filtering */
if (args) {
  const searchText = args[0];
  const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
  const match = value.match(re);
  // If there's no match, just return the original value.
  if (!match) {
    return value;
  }
  value = value.replace(re, '<mark class="saqr-first-mark">' + match[0] + '</mark>');
  return observableOf(value);
}
```

and in the material datatable typescript file I add the highlight  into the constructor

```
constructor(
private highlight: HighlightSearchPipe,
 ) {}

applyFilter() {
 this.dataSource.filter = this.searchKeyword.trim().toLowerCase();
 this.highlight.transform(this.dataSource.filter, this.searchKeyword);  
// here cannot detect that 
}
```

What do you suggest to do for data table highlighting the searched text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've managed to produce a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8px7je?file=app/table-filtering-example.html) of this. My `HighlightSearchPipe` class is as follows:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlightSearch'
})
export class HighlightSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, search: string): string {
    const valueStr = value + ''; // Ensure numeric values are converted to strings
    return valueStr.replace(new RegExp('(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(' + search + ')(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)', 'gi'), '<strong class="your-class">$1</strong>');
  }
}
```

I've modified Typescript class that contains the `applyFilter()` function as follows:

i. Added the `filterText` class variable so the filter text typed by the user can be accessed in the HTML. This variable is updated in the `applyFilter()` function

ii. Removed the call to `this.highlight.transform(this.dataSource.filter, this.searchKeyword);` in `applyFilter()`

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class TableFilteringExample {
  ...
  filterText = '';

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.filterText = filterValue.trim();
    this.dataSource.filter = this.filterText.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

In the component HTML I've changed the way the cells are rendered from:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

to:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="element.name | highlightSearch: filterText"></td>
</ng-container>
```

This way the cell value (in this case `element.name`) is capable of rendering HTML. It uses the `highlightSearch` pipe in order to transform the value and highlight the portion of it that matches the filter.

Comment: if the string contains any html elements, this won't work